# Aws ec2 and Route 53 domain

Tags: amazon-route53

I'm banging my head against the wall at the moment. 
What am I doing wrong here? 
Your help would be much appreciated!

I started with AWS, bought a domain with route 53 and thought I could easily start using it.

Have made an A record with the server IP [static IP].

[image]

This seems to result in a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN domain that can't be reached. 
Even after waiting for hours.

Next solution I found on the web was setting a CNAME record;

[image]

This doesn't seem to work either. 
What am I doing wrong here, any suggestions?

Thank you for your input
I have been learning a lot about AWS and it's quite handy.

[update]
* I found the dns name at the elastic IP settings [public DNS]

Comment: Please tell us more about how you configured Route 53. What steps do you take to obtain the DNS name and add it to Route 53? What appears under "Registered Domains"? What appears under "Hosted zones"? (You can edit your question to add details.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

When you register the domain, Amazon has set the nameservers, these nameservers on the register page and route53 were different. This is why I couldn't point the domain to my IP.

After setting them the same; the domain was pointing to my server.

Answer (score 1):

Step to do this :

1. Create A record of domain
2. Give same EC2 IP to A record
3. Change Security group of EC2 for port 80 and 443( if using) to all
4. Also try to ping EC2 IP by opening ssh port.

If do this all carefully. Then for IP changes sometime take times.

To see whether changes reflected or not.

Ubuntu :

open : /etc/hosts file and record for this.

```
terminal > sudo nano /etc/hosts/
```

add entry this file

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.xample.com
```

and save and close

then try to ping your domain and hit from browser. if this works then revert file changes. wait for Route53 to reflect changes in A record.